# Data always resets to original state on heroku free account after some time

Tags: django, postgresql, heroku

I have deployed my django app into heroku free account.(first time)
In my working environment I use SQLLite on Heroku I assume POstgres should work.

However I am confused whats going on.

So first of all the app is up and running the data that was in my SQLlite database is currently shows at my deployed app.

Is it because my SQLLite DB was copied to heroku and this is what I actually see?

Another issue that indicates somthing is wron with DB is that if I create superuser via terminal I cant log with it to my app.

Another issue is that it looks data constantly restores to its original state after some time .

I followed the instructions and this is what I have in my settings for DB

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}

import dj_database_url
db_from_env = dj_database_url.config()
DATABASES['default'].update(db_from_env)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because that is how Heroku works. The file system is ephemeral and you must not store anything on it; but sqlite does store is data there, so it will get reset every time a new dyno is started.

Your reference to postgres is confusing. You are not using postgres, but you must.

Comment: Thanks that means it is mandatory to use POSTGRES locally before I do upload .

I am really confused what should I have in my settings file.Just connectivity to my local POSTGRES?

Comment: No, it doesn't mean any such thing. You should treat your local and production databases as completely separate.

Comment: Thanks , but I am still confused. 
I assumed that by adding - import dj_database_url
db_from_env = dj_database_url.config()
DATABASES['default'].update(db_from_env)

to my settings file after it deployed to heroku it will figure out to what DB in Postgres to connect  and it dose not matter what was originally configured there

Comment: You're going to need to convert your app to use Postgres locally. That doesn't mean you have to have a local copy of Postgres install, but that is an option. You can also sign up for an account at a postgres as a service provider like elephant sql.

If your app doesn't already, you'll need to set up at least a basic config so that you can use the environment variables in your code to tell it where the db is. Then when your app is running locally, it will point to where your local env var says, and on Heroku, it'll use what the Heroku env vars are set to.